# Compare 2 Files using AWK based on a dynamic column as a variable and print the differences A-B and B-A

Tags: bash, shell, compare

File 1:

```
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5O'|'5042449534546015801549'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5O'|'5042449534546015801677'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701541'
```

File 2:

```
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701548'
```

OutPut i want is A-B and as well as B-A

I tried the Below command but it seems not working..

```
var1=5
awk -F "|" -v col="$var1" 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} !($col in a)' File1 File2
awk -F "|" -v col="$var1" 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} !($col in a)' File1 File2
```

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, the mistake I was doing is giving wrong column number in
`{a[$2];next}`

I have to compare the 5th Column to it will be like:

```
awk -F "|" -v col="$var1" 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next} !($col in a)' File1 File2
awk -F "|" -v col="$var1" 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next} !($col in a)' File1 File2
```

Comment: Add the correct formatting in your questions and comments please. Check the tips where explain how to do that

Comment: this should not be considered as an answer, it was just a typo in your initial code